# Requerying MS Access Form Causes Filter Not to Be Applied

Tags: forms, ms-access, filtering

Recently, I started noticing odd behavior with one of my continuous forms. It contains text boxes in the header which can be used to filter the list. For some reason, whenever this form is requeried, for example when a record is edited or added in another form, this form reverts to its unfiltered state.

I stepped through the code and played around with some variables in the immediate window. The filter is still there, it just isn't being applied. Setting Me.FilterOn = True does nothing, as it is already true. A work around is easy, I can set Me.Filter = Me.Filter, but I would like to find out what is causing this behavior in the first place.

I have other contiunous forms that work completely fine; requerying them does not do anything to the filter. I'm assuming I changed some setting on the problematic form, but I have no idea what. I compared all the settings between the two forms in the property window and found nothing. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out what was wrong. I realized the query that the form was based on was a pass-through query. As soon as I changed it to a normal access query, the problem went away.

Unfortunately I had it as a pass-through query for a reason. Mircosoft Access doesn't like my join. Sometimes it throws me a join not supported error, and other times it just gives me screwed up results... Looks like I'll have to rethink this query.